# nginx not serving correct react build content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack

I have a react app. When I build my app via the dev server (localhost: 3000), the app is served correctly with the correct styling etc.

However, when I serve via nginx (via docker) I get a completely different UI? Does anyone know why this may be?

I don't think it is a docker issue. I am using webpack if this is something that I may need to look at?

My nginx config:

```
server {
  listen    80 default_server;
  listen    [::]:80 default_server;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location = / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.16-alpine
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY public/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

[image][image]

Comment: Did you write the docker file on your own? Do you understand what this line does? `COPY public/ /usr/share/nginx/html/` And what's your build path for the react project?

Comment: No, i got some guidance from some other SO posts. I'm unsure what that line does. Build path is     ```entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }```

Comment: Okay, let's call the project folder `root`, and your build files are under `root/public`?

Comment: Yes that’s xorrect

Comment: Can you attach screenshots of the correct UI and the wrong one?

Comment: They are attached to the original post

Comment: I can only see one screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249900/discussion-between-boogiehsows-and-dream-bold).

Answer (score 1):

It loads default NGINX configuration. You should add;

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

to your docker file.

It should solve your issue.